# Bibliography header in small caps

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, amsbook

I am using the amsbook class together with the natbib package and I would like to change the appearance of the bibliography header: Instead of normalfont letters I would like to have small caps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\bibliography{../bib/alias}
\end{document}
```

This is how the bibliography header currently looks like:
[image]

How do I change the bibliography header? Help is very much appreciated!

Comment: You could try putting `\clearpage\renewcommand{\leftmark}{\textsc{\bibname}}\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\leftmark}` before `\bibliography...` but that might have unintended consequences especially if there's anything after the bibliography. Is there?

Comment: Try this: `\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section*{\textsc{Bibliography}}}` ETA: Actually, this would change the title of the section. If you want to change the header on each page, @frabjous solution would be the way to go.

Comment: @Ingmar - Since the OP is using the `amsbook` document class, it should be `\chapter*`, not `\section*`, right?

Comment: How about `\renewcommand\bibname{\textsc{Bibliography}}`. (If you want to use smallcaps in the headers, you shoud use it in the chapter-level title as well, right?)

Comment: @Mico Probably, but your approach is cleaner anyway.

Comment: @frabjous Your solution just works well for me. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mico your solution would affect the heading and ToC as well, which I think is not wanted.

Comment: @frabjous - It depends on whether the OT1 or the T1 font encoding will be in effect. Your comment applies to the T1-encoding case.

Comment: @Mico For me it affects the TOC with either encoding.